# Is is true that it is quicker if I print one object at a time multiple times, as opposed to printing a batch of them?

Tags: speed

I need to print so many of this model:

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4160638

[image]

When I print just one of them, the printer head has a focus on one area and prints it with the least amount of head movement.

When I print a batch of them, the printer head needs to keep moving to the area of each object. It seems that increased print time is not a linear multiple of the number of objects. It is more than that.

I wanted to ask everyone's experience to see if I am missing anything here. Is it true that it is quicker if I print one object at a time multiple times, as opposed to printing a batch of them?

Comment: This is [asked before](/q/3661/); does that answer your question?

Comment: Note that printing multiple objects on the build plate increases the chance for the nozzle to catch a print, this can destroy a whole plate on objects, while a single print would only loose that single print. If your printer is reliable this may be less of a concern. Also small prints require relative large amount of preparation and may not print over night, so you loose time to print.

Comment: @0scar, yes, that nailed it. I was looking for the "sequential printing feature"